# How can I only submit a build to a specific test group?

Tags: app-store-connect

So the point of these groups is that you can release builds to certain people. I also learned that these are external testing only. Which is fine. What I am not understanding though is, if I have a test flight internal users already (20 or so) and I want to submit a build and ONLY have it available for the group and NOT everyone else (internal users), how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I think I was able to do this by submitting 2 builds, the first being the build I want to go to the group only. I essentially just upload at same time, but making sure the build i want to test is first. This is because the internal testing group just gets the latest build. So if you submit 2 at a time, first being the group only, and the second one thats okay to go to the internal, you can then select the build you want on the group while still have the others go to internal.

So dumb, I should be able to set the build to the group only without it going to internal testing. Thats the point of a group!